# prevent firing the code-behind event from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I would like this ASP button control to stop calling its event handler when the JavaScript client method `IsCorrectPrice()` returns false.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:IsCorrectPrice()"/>


btnsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
  Handles btnsubmit.Click
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `OnClientClick` to be like this:

```
OnClientClick="return IsCorrectPrice();"
```

Comment: Just `return IsCorrectPrice();` is enough

Comment: thank you very much p.campbell and Ghostoy, both of your answers work! :)

Comment: @Liz: thanks! Be sure to use the green checkmark to 'accept' an answer for all your StackOverflow questions. It's part of the reputation system.

Comment: Hello! I just found an issue regarding this. I added a validation group so this what happened, even when the IsCorrectPrice() return true but the validation group has an error, it still posts back. I found out that validationgroup logic comes after the clientscript. So now, i used the original answer of p.campbell - OnClientClick="if(!IsCorrectPrice()) return false;" Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use jQuery, you could use this..

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
   if (!IsCorrectPrice()) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

*Note:

Using the `OnClientClick` right there in the DOM starts to get unmaintainable after the most basic scenarios.

Also, the `#btnsubmit` may not be the exact id of your button, but that depends on what version of ASP.Net you are using and if you are using 4, what your ClientIdMode is set to.

Comment: Thank you very much ar3, I will keep this in mind whenever I use jQuery. :)